# Record getting created in custom object without giving value for Required field

Tags: custom-object, validation, required-field

I have a custom object that has a custom field marked as required. When I try to insert data in the object without giving value for the required field, record is getting created. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. The field is not required.
   It may be flagged as required on the page layout or on the flexi page, but if you check from Setup > Object Manager > *Object Name* > Fields & Relationship you'll see it isn't required.
   In this case if you try to create a new record from standard UI keeping that field blank an error will show up on save action, but you'll be able to create it from apex or from api.
2. The field is required and there is a process (trigger or flow) that set it before the record is saved to the database.

Keep in mind that you could [set up debug logging](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) for your users in order to know what happens when you create a record.

Comment: There was a default value mapped to the field which I failed to notice.

Answer (score 0):

When we set default value to required fields, even though the developer/user fails to enter input to the required field, the record will be saved with the default value.